# What's the difference between SetFocus() and Focus() in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I can use both in the code behind:

SetFocus() - "Sets the browser focus to the specified control."

Focus() - "Sets input focus to a control."

In practice, what's the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Page.SetFocus` can accept a control's client ID as a string instead of a reference to the control itself, which may be useful if you can't get a reference to the control to call its Focus method.

`control.Focus()` is identical to `Page.SetFocus(control)`. In fact, all is does is call SetFocus...

```
public virtual void Focus()
{
    this.Page.SetFocus(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232.aspx):

> To set focus on an ASP.NET Web server
>   control
>
> Call the control's Focus method.
>
> -or-
>
> Call the page's SetFocus method,
>   passing it the ID of the control on
>   which you want to set focus.

Comment: In other words, the Focus method is on the control level whereas the SetFocus method is on the page level and must know what to set focus on.